# LLVM: -Wno-ignored-qualifiers equivalent?

Tags: gcc, llvm, clang

With GCC, when the `-Wall -Wextra` flags are enabled, one has the option of disabling warnings such as the following with `-Wno-ignored-qualifiers`:

```
warning: 'const' type qualifier on return type has no effect
```

Is there any way to achieve the same behavior with LLVM/Clang? I Googled it, but only found some patch related pages about how this error reporting feature got added. Nothing on how to disable it.

I am using LLVM & Clang version 3.0 (build from SVN sources).

*Note*: I was going to post this on SuperUser, but there's not a single question about Clang there and no LLVM tag either, so that kind of discouraged me. If this question should be there anyway, feel free to move it.

*[Edit]* It seems the option is recognized when I run my Makefile from the terminal. When ran from Eclipse (Helios), it doesn't get recognized however.

**[Solution]** Found it. Apparently, the problem was Eclipse (under Ubuntu) is started by root. Why this is, I have no idea, but the effect is that the $PATH variable contains what root would have, instead what the user starting Eclipse would have. As such, Eclipse was using an older system-wide installed version of Clang (2.80). Adding the correct PATH variable in Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Environment fixed this.

Comment: I think that is the appropriate S.E. site for this type of quesiton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Clang are you using? `-Wno-ignored-qualifiers` works for me:

```
% clang -Wall -Wextra -c foo.c
foo.c:1:1: warning: 'const' type qualifier on return type has no effect
      [-Wignored-qualifiers]
const int foo();
^~~~~
1 warning generated.
% clang -Wall -Wextra -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -c foo.c
%
```

In general you can look at the `.td` files, which do a pretty nice job of collecting all the diagnostics.  (There's a TODO in the Clang docs to autogenerate documentation with tblgen, but this hasn't been done yet.)

In this case for example you see in [`DiagnosticSemaKinds.td`](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/include/clang/Basic/DiagnosticSemaKinds.td):

```
def warn_qual_return_type : Warning< 
  "'%0' type qualifier%s1 on return type %plural{1:has|:have}1 no effect">,
  InGroup<IgnoredQualifiers>, DefaultIgnore;
```

which shows you what diagnostic group it's in (`IgnoredQualifiers`).  Then you can look in [`DiagnosticGroups.td`](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/include/clang/Basic/DiagnosticGroups.td) to see what `IgnoredQualifiers` is called on the command line:

```
def IgnoredQualifiers : DiagGroup<"ignored-qualifiers">;
```

So `-Wno-ignored-qualifiers` is it.  Clang tries to be GCC-compatible wherever possible, so using the GCC name for something is usually likely to work.

Comment: @nicholas-riley clang version 3.0 (trunk 127980). Just noticed something very strange, in the terminal the option does work, in Eclipse, it doesn't.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Eclipse then.

Comment: Yeah, I've been searching, but can't find anything about it. Quite annoying, now I have to disable -Wall, otherwise I get about 120 warnings and because of that I can't see the interesting errors. Oh well...

Comment: wrt TODO, I'm on it :) The first part has been completed (enhancing the diagnostics) and I'll begin working on the second part soon... I do it in my spare time though, so you might have to wait a month or two.

Comment: @Matthieu: Great to know. Good luck :-)